# merging file-move into a branch with svn

Tags: svn, merge

What's the best way to handle the following situation?

Development is going parallel on trunk and a branch; a file x is different in the two locations.
Due to code reorganization file x is moved to another folder in trunk (svn detects this and keeps revision history - so far so good). 
The last change, in which file x is moved to another folder, is merged to branch. (this is only a change to the working copy at this point)
On commit in branch, file x's branch-changes are wiped out of branch and replaced with trunk's version. Svn retains file x's history as it thinks that file x originates from the trunk.

Using TortioseSVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe this is correct - file X does originate from trunk (through I guess you should ave seen a tree conflict message). When you committed, you committed the 'file x was moved from a to b' operation, so looking at the history will follow file X back to the trunk.

The easiest way round this is to manually copy the trunk version across and commit that, ignoring the 'file move' operation revision.

Comment: Thanks. In this case I had a large number of moved files affected but only some of these files are different by content in the branch. Is there a more automated way?

Comment: more automated - probably merge and commit most of the changes, then simply copy the trunk over the top of your working copy and commit, so all un-merged changes will be committed then. Assuming you're only updating existing files, though all moves should ave been handled by the merge.